# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim.summarization'

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, summarization

I am Doing Text Analytics using NLP.
My is Task: Reading PDF content and summarization.
I used this : from gensim.summarization import summarize
But Got a error : I tried in  Google collab and everywhere.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim.summarization'

Want a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 7):

The summarization subpackage was removed from gensim in version 4. From the [gensim version 4 release notes](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/releases/tag/4.0.1): #2958: Remove gensim.summarization subpackage, docs and test data, by @mpenkov.

If you still want to use `gensim.summarization.summarize` you will need to install an earlier version of gensim, such as 3.8.2. For example: `pip3 install "gensim==3.8.2"`

Comment: `3.8.3` best pre-4.0 version to use, if you must. But Gensim's `summarization` code was removed because it only offered a weak form of 'extractive' summarization – guessing important sentences in text – in way that wasn't very performant, consistent w/ other Gensim code, or customizable/maintainable/improvable. I've never seen a good demo showing it work well, & while a few rare use cases in English may have found it helpful, I believe most users who tried it left feeling it was a frustrating waste of time. Newer techniques, especially LLM-based, can do far better 'abstractive' summarization.